# E4X in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, e4x

Apache NiFi has an *ExecuteScript* processor with *ECMAScript* as one of the possible script engines. But even with Rhino JAR in NiFi /lib folder I still cannot create an XML object as any E4X example suggests. (PS. DOM, etc. are not the options.)

To begin with *org.mozilla.javascript.xmlimpl.XML* is not a public class, but even then it seems to be called as *org.mozilla.javascript.xmlimpl.XML.jsConstructor()* under the hood.

Any idea how to add E4X support to ECMAScript NiFi?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible. Even the idea of adding support directly to Nashorn got [no love from the OpenJDK folks](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037409).

Comment: This sounds as a necessity to build my own ExcecuteScript based on Rhino JS engine. Another feature that would be useful to have is groups and global variables that can be populated on (e.g., group) start to cache content of XML schema, XSLT and schematron files.

Comment: An alternative is to use Groovy instead of JS, the former has good built-in support for XML.

Comment: Parsing XML with Groovy is fine, but MarkupBuilder is good only for something very simple.